# Is there a way to update the weights of a layer/variable directly after a training step?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

There are ways to get and update the weight directly outside of training, but what I am looking to do is after the each training step and after the gradients have updated a particular variable or layer, I would like to save those weights to file and then replace the layer or variable weights with brand new ones. And then continue with the next step (forward pass using the new values in the variable or layer, then backward pass with the calculated loss/gradients) of training.

I have thought about just calling each training step individually, but I am wondering if that is somehow very time/memory inefficient.

Comment: ok in pytprch you can save and load model with torch.load, torch.save ( see doc) and you can do that manually after weights are updated means after optimizer.step(), what is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use a `Callback` to do that.

Define the function you want:

```
def afterBatch(batch, logs):
    model.save_weights('weights'+str(batch)) #maybe you want also a method to save the current epoch....

    #option 1
    model.layers[select_a_layer].set_weights(listOfNumpyWeights) #not sure this works

    #option 2
    K.set_value(model.layers[select_a_layer].kernel, newValueInNumpy) 
       #depending on the layer you have kernel, bias and maybe other weight names 
       #take a look at the source code of the layer you are changing the weights
```

Use a `LambdaCallback`:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

batchCallback = LambdaCallback(on_batch_end = aterBatch)
model.fit(x, y, callbacks = [batchCallback, ....])
```

There are weight updates after every batch (this might be too much if you are saving weights every time). You can also try `on_epoch_end` instead of `on_batch_end`.